# Make only one column of table select-able and copy-able to paste in excel sheet

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, css

I am making a dashboard type web page in which I'll call queries from `database: Oracle` and result will be shown on the web page. The problem is that I am showing more than one column in the `table` as result and I want to copy data of only one column and make this pasteable to excel or `spreadsheet` so that every cell of the table will be pasted in a different cell of the sheet.

I tried many solutions which are making my only one column selectable but it is not helping me because when I copy and paste this text in google sheet all the data is pasted in a single cell.

But I need to copy table column data to Spread sheet Column

**Example:**

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>col-1</td>
        <td>col-2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>col-1</td>
        <td>col-2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>col-1</td>
        <td>col-2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>col-1</td>
        <td>col-2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>col-1</td>
        <td>col-2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>col-1</td>
        <td>col-2</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

The HTML Output is as below:

```
col-1    col-2
col-1    col-2
col-1    col-2
col-1    col-2
col-1    col-2
```

I need to copy only the data:

```
col-2
col-2
col-2
col-2
col-2
```

I need to paste in the spreadsheet in same column and 5 different cells.

Comment: What have you tried? This can be done with VBA

Comment: I am using `PHP`, `javascript`, `jQuery` and `Oracle`